# Pfaffian definition for a complex skew-Hermitian matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices, pfaffian

Normally, the Pfaffian is defined for real skew-symmetric matrices $A = -A^T$, and some authors extend this to complex skew-symmetric matrices.   Is there a straightforward generalization of the Pfaffian to complex skew-*Hermitian* matrices $A = -A^* \ne A^T$, however?

(Note that $\sqrt{\det A}$ is not sufficient because it doesn't tell you the sign.)

Comment: There may be something if you add some restrictions. You can see the need for restrictions with the $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ cases though.